# Compute multiplication (element-wise) over multiple batches of images using broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network, array-broadcasting

I am currently working on the mnist dataset to create a CNN.
My input is

```
X:  Array of shape (batch_size, n_channels, image_height, image_width)
F: The filter to apply. Array of shape (n_channels, filter_height, filter_width)
```

I am able to compute the element-wise multiplication on a single filter as below:

```
index : tuple pointing to the top-left corner of where Kernel to be placed
f_shape = np.shape(F)
np.multiply(X[:, :, index[0]:index[0] + f_shape[1], index[1]:index[1] + f_shape[2]], F)
```

But now, I want to compute the element-wise multiplication over multiple filters.
So my input will be:

```
X:  Array of shape (batch_size, n_channels, image_height, image_width)
F: The filter to apply. Array of shape (n_filters, n_channels, filter_height, filter_width)
```

I am not able figure out an efficient numpy operation using broadcasting to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You want `skimage.util.view_as_windows` for both cases.  In addition, `np.multiply` does not do dot products, `np.dot` does.  Or in this case (when tracking many dimensions) `np.einsum`

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

x_window = view_as_windows(X, (n_channels, filter_height, filter_width)).squeeze()

single_filter_mult = np.einsum('ijkmnp, mnp -> ijkmnp', x_window, F)
single_filter_dot = np.einsum('ijkmnp, mpq -> ijklmq', x_window, F)
multi_filter_mult = np.einsum('ijkmnp, lmnp -> ijklmnp', x_window, F_multi)
multi_filter_dot = np.einsum('ijkmnp, lmpq -> ijklmnq', x_window, F_multi)
```

now `*_filter_*[index]` will give the expected output.